# In product page call a function from functions.php to add a custom price to basket

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

A product has price of 100, with javascript I am making a sum of 100 + 50 and when I press add to cart button I need to have that product with price of 150 in cart.

I also only allow 1 single product in cart.

I made possible the change of price with a fixed price but I don't know how to pass the value from product page to this function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 1000, 1);
function add_custom_price( $cart ) {
    // This is necessary for WC 3.0+
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    // Avoiding hook repetition (when using price calculations for example | optional)
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( 150 ); // this is the custom price
    }
}
```

any help please? thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: because I have to add some extra prices on product price / order total and its not something fixed, think they are random

Comment: What do you mean by « think they are random »?

Comment: getting like 10000 extraprices with javascript, I need to add that to final price, cant add them in woo so how to set custom price?

Comment: At any rate, you can get the price with `$cart_item['data']->get_price()`, then add 50 to it and do `$cart_item['data']->set_price(newPrice)`.

Comment: 50 it's not fixed price, this price I only have it on product page, from there I have to pass it to total

Comment: To get the price from the frontend to the backend, there are multiile options. You could set a cookie, or you could add a GET parameter to the url (maybe add it to the `action` attribute of the `form` in which the cart is wrapped).